# Issue with displaying 3D plot in python from 3D array values

Tags: python

I have a 3d array with intensities value i.e. i have a value for each P[x,y,x]. Now I want to display the intensity values in 3D plot with intensity bar. How can be this done in python. Thanks in advance

Comment: The standard libraries don't have 3D rendering capability, so you'll have to find a third party library to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much kevin. You have any suggestion on this

Comment: Nope, I haven't got any experience with rendering. Library recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow in any case.